# Fedora - Xenomai RTDM - Can not allocate memory

Tags: linux, real-time, linux-device-driver, device-driver, xenomai

I tried to run tut01-skeleton-derv.c example under xenomai-x.x/examples/rtdm/deriver-api/. I run makefile without error. The command of in tut01-skeleton-derv.c file says that :

To test this application, you just need to:

```
 $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path of xenomai>/lib
 $ insmod tut01-skeleton-drv.ko
 $ ./tut01-skeleton-app
```

Firstly, I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/xenomai/lib/` on terminal, it was ok. When I run `sudo insmod tut01-skeleton-drv.ko`, an error occured. "Could not insert module tut01-skeleton-drv.ko: Can not allocate memory". What should I do?

Comment: Are you actually running `insmod` as a regular user and not root? Usually you need to be root to load kernel modules.

Comment: I try "sudo insmod tut01-skeleton-drv.ko", there is same error.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` does not use the local environment variable. So when you run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/xenomai/lib/` as a user then sudo your next command, the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set. Try to change user to root then run the commands.